# PCI Compliance - App hosted on AWS no card data stored

Tags: payment-processing, pci-compliance

I am researching PCI compliance for an app I plan to build. It would essentially be an online market place. I will be using MangoPay as the payment processor (who are level 1 PCI compliant) along with their SDK to send information to them. No card information would be stored within the app.

The app it self would be hosted on AWS (which itself is level 1 compliant https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/pci-dss-level-1-faqs/).

**Question**
What level PCI certification would I need to get in order to be compliant.

Comment: Are you planning to route the card data through your app servers, or have it sent direct from the users' devices to MangoPay?

Comment: Directly from the user's device to MangoPay